# How to get rid of extra pie charts in iReport/Jasper?

Tags: java, charts, jasper-reports

I generated a pie chart using iReport and when I went to preview mode, it spat out lots of useless pie charts (i.e. 1 chart with 1 of the 4 categories, next chart  with 2 of the 4 categories, and so on... until a total of 3 charts are reached). My query is completely fine. When I tested the query on the DB (which is also the data source, it gave me:

```
category count

A     2

B     1

C     3

D     3
```

What do I need to do to get a proper pie chart with all 4 categories in it>

Comment: What band do you have the pie chart in? Can you attach your JRXML? I have never used the charts before, but my guess is you have it in the detail band, which is making it act all funny.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This page has my answer, except increment and reset settings also must be set properly in addition to what's listed there:

[Creating Pie Chart in iReport (4.6.0)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11461704/creating-pie-chart-in-ireport-4-6-0?rq=1)